# Jupyter Notebook uses my system's python3.4 instead of anaconda's python3.5 as a kernel

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter

I had anaconda2 installed, and manually added the python3 kernel, so I could chose between python2 and python3. The problem was that I added my system's python3 binary, not anaconda's, so I was missing all the libraries that anaconda brings. Specifically I couldnt import 'from scipy.misc import imread'.

So I deleted anaconda2, installed anaconda3, but my jupyter notebook still uses my system's old python3 kernel. When I run sys.version inside the jupyter notebook I get python 3.4, but when I run it inside ipython in console I get python 3.5, with all the modules I need good to go.

So how do I tell jupyter notebook specifically what bin to use as a kernel?

Comment: what does `ls $(jupyter --data-dir)/kernels` print?

Comment: @cel ls: cannot access /home/ubuntu/.local/share/jupyter/kernels: No such file or directory

Comment: `which -a jupyter` is the next I'd check

Answer (score 1):

Ended up solving it with:

pip install -U ipython

ipython3 kernelspec install-self